# Divisibility of Dirichlet L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $k$ be an even integer and $p$ a prime number such that $p-1|k$.

Suppose that $p$ does not divide $L(1-k,\chi)$ and $L(1-k,\psi)$, where $\chi$ and $\psi$ are quadratic characters.

Can we deduce that $p$ does not divide $L(1-k,\chi.\psi)$?

Answer (score 10):

This is trivially false, infinitely many counterexamples exist.
A simple one: p = 5, k = 4, $D(\chi)=12$, $D(\psi)=13$ then
$L(\chi,-3)=36$, $L(\psi,-3)=58$ but $L(\chi.\psi,-3)=365800$.

Comment: if we fixes one character can we find another one such that the implication in my question is true ?

Comment: how did you find those counter-examples ? did you look at a table of the [generalized Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generalized_Bernoulli_numbers) ?